# On Yocto, is there a way to ship the image rootfs manifest in the image?

Tags: yocto

Yocto generates a rootfs.manifest in the image folder. Would it be possible to also ship it in the roofts easily?

I tried using `ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND_append` but this cannot work because the manifest is shipped after.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `IMAGE_PREPROCESS_COMMAND`. Do refer to the  [manual on the same.](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.3.1/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-IMAGE_PREPROCESS_COMMAND)